# User account pages seem to be slightly broken

Tags: bug, design

Parts of the user account pages on physics.SE are "out of alignment":

[image]

This effect appears to me on accounts other than my own, too, but only here on physics.SE (account pages on math.SE, for example, look fine). I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 on Windows 7 64-bit.

The same problem is [now being reported on SciFi.SE, IT Security.SE, and Bicycles.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1905/2285). I also see it on Electronics.SE.

Comment: Huh, I see the same thing using Firefox 11 on Linux.

Comment: And Firefox 11 on Max OS 10.5. But Stack Overflow does not have this problem. Nor does CodeGolf or SciFi. We seem to be special.

Comment: Same for Chrome on Linux.

Comment: Was getting this earlier on UX (http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/990/user-info-improperly-styled-on-user-profile) not getting it anymore. It seems to be intermittent? Think it's time to take it to MetaSO?